# Aggregator behavior on server restart - spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, aggregator

Premise -

In spring integration,if i have a aggregator with a message group which is incomplete. Before group release stratergy is met, server is restarted.

- Current Behavior->
  all the messages posted to the aggregator go to the same message group and not a new one, since it is not marked complete, messages keep flowing in.
- Expected->
  If server is restarted, aggregator picks the left over messages from message store, marks already persisted ones complete & then cater new ones,

Is my expectation incorrect? Can somebody guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can reach your requirements with `MessageGroupStoreReaper`, which you will run just on the server startup, e.g. via catching `ContextRefreshedEvent`:

> The MessageGroupStore maintains a list of these callbacks which it applies, on demand, to all messages whose timestamp is earlier than a time supplied as a parameter (see the registerMessageGroupExpiryCallback(..) and expireMessageGroups(..) methods above).
>
> The expireMessageGroups method can be called with a timeout value. Any message older than the current time minus this value will be expired, and have the callbacks applied. Thus it is the user of the store that defines what is meant by message group "expiry".

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#reaper

Comment: Thanks Artem, I have such a reaper in place which runs via a cron every day 2000 hours. With what you are saying, please correct me if wrong is if the server is up at specified time, it will anyways do a clean up of all messages persisted the previous day? Is it?

Comment: Right, that is my idea. Not sure in your existing `reaper`, but this new one should be be called only once from the application startup. The `timeout` can be just `0` to clean up everything in the `MessageStore`. Since it is  anew start, that is obvious that all existing messages in the store are outdated, therefore have to be cleaned.

Comment: Great! So, that's time to accept the answer to close the question as solved.